# How to test if the AUC of two ROC curves are different?

Tags: r, roc, auc, statistical-test

I have to test if the AUC of two ROC curves (of two classifiers) are different or not using a permutation test (I can't use `roc.test` function, it's an exercise for university)

After some research, I tried to use a Mann Whitney test but I'm sure it's not the good solution and I don't know how to find that good solution. At university we saw that same algorithm with a comparison of two means with `t.test` but not the case of comparison of 2 AUC. What test should I use? Should I do the algorithm differently?

Here's my code :

```
pred1 = prediction(prob1,y) #  pred1 is my first classifier
perf1.auc = performance(pred1, measure = "auc")
auc1<-perf1.auc@y.values[[1]] # first AUC (= 0.919357)

pred2 = prediction(prob2,y) # pred2 is my second classifier
perf2.auc = performance(pred2, measure = "auc")
auc2<-perf2.auc@y.values[[1]] # second AUC (= 0.9412217)

t0 = wilcox.test(auc1,auc2,paired=FALSE)$statistic # Tried a Mann Whitney test, not the good solution
```

---

```
z = c(prob1,prob2)
set.seed(27)
B = 1000 # Number of iterations
t.perm = numeric(B)

for(b in 1:B){
  z1 = sample(z, replace = F) # Resampling
  prob11 = z1[1:length(prob1)]
  prob22 = z1[(length(prob1)+1):length(z1)]
  
  pred11 = prediction(prob11,y)
  perf11.auc = performance(pred11, measure = "auc")
  auc11<-perf11.auc@y.values[[1]]
  
  pred22 = prediction(prob22,y)
  perf22.auc = performance(pred22, measure = "auc")
  auc22<-perf22.auc@y.values[[1]]

  t.perm[b] =wilcox.test(auc11,auc22,paired=FALSE)$statistic # Tried a Mann Whitney test, not the good solution
}

t.perm = c(t.perm, t0)
pval = mean(abs(t.perm) >= abs(t0))
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for roc.test? It contains some pointers that should be relevant for your task...